# All Chrome-based browsers have fractional pixel size on my system

Tags: google-chrome, browser, chromium, scaling

I'm using an Ubuntu-based OS with XOrg as the display server. I don't have system-wide scaling enabled, and if I open [this test](https://svelte.dev/repl/cc00e921c21948ada4b7f6ac91e0b1d4?version=3.58.0) in Firefox, it shows that the [`displayPixelRatio`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicePixelRatio) is 1. However, if I open the same test in any Chromium-based browser, it shows me that my scaling factor is 1.03125. Close to one, but not quite.

This really frustrates me, as I'm a web developer and this fractional scaling causes all kinds of weird subtle artifacts where small UI elements appear off by one pixel. This is especially visible if there are two small elements that are supposed to have the same size, but one of them "randomly" gets another pixel of width.

How do Chromium-based decide the pixel ratio they're going to use? Is there any way to just use the value of 1?